# custom on submit notification for google form included in website

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, google-sheets

**I try to make validation google form built-in website and show custom notification when form is submitted.**

- For form validation i use [jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) — all working
  great.
- I find tips how to use [catching on submit and show notification in
  iframe](http://www.2webvideo.com/customizing-google-docs-form-for-email-validation-with-free-jquery-script)

> For me needed show div and hide form if from submitted.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {

   $("#ss-form").validate({meta: "validate"});

   function showHide() {
      $('#form_is_submitted').css('display', 'block');
      $('#ss-form').css('display', 'none');
   }
});
</script>

<div id="form_is_submitted" style="display:none;">ok! form is submitted</div>

<form action="spreadsheet link" id="ss-form" method='post' onsubmit="showHide(); return false;">
                               ...form code...
</form>
```

this code not working right...
is redirected to notification via google form

**what am I doing wrong?**

---

**EDIT**

When i use this code — i see my notification (#form_is_submitted) and form was validated but information not was submitted to a google spreadsheet

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#ss-form').validate({ 
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('#form_is_submitted').css('display', 'block');
            $('#ss-form').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });


});

    </script>

    <div id="form_is_submitted" style="display:none;">ok! form is submitted</div>

    <form action="spreadsheet link" id="ss-form" method='post'>
                                   ...form code...
    </form>
```

---

When i use this code — form was validated, information was submitted to google spreadsheet but page was redirected to a google form notification.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#ss-form").validate({meta: "validate"});

   });

 </script>

    <div id="form_is_submitted" style="display:none;">ok! form is submitted</div>

    <form action="spreadsheet link" id="ss-form" method='post'>
                                   ...form code...
    </form>
```

For earlier sorry for stupid mistakes, I'm trying to sort out this problem

Comment: Not sure if it will help but you've spelled display wrong in your jQuery. It should be display not dispaly.

Comment: I made a mistake when I wrote this post, but the problem is that still going to redirect to notification via google form. I want to see my notification if form submitted.

Comment: Explain more about exactly what you want this to do and what it's doing instead.  Simply saying "not working right" is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the advice of Sparky.

```
<style>
#hidden_iframe,
#form_is_submitted{
    display: none;
}
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#ss-form").validate({meta: "validate"});

        $('#ss-form').submit(function () {
            if ($("#ss-form").valid() == true) { 
               $('#form_is_submitted').css('display', 'block');
               $("#ss-form").css('display', 'none');
               return true;
            }
        });

   });
</script>

<div id="form_is_submitted">ok!</div>

<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe"></iframe>

<form action="google_form_link" method="POST" id="ss-form" target="hidden_iframe">

    ..form code..

</form>
```

- **[spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqmhWQ_A7q_adFZxazJLNjdaX0JOOW1CYWpTZ1pLbHc#gid=0)**
- **[form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1OKdiKB_bWtYHldIR_agoaG2hW8_MLKcVHUXGe2A1r6o/viewform)**
- **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2pwww/HmVqj/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you're doing here but using an inline `onSubmit` handler is totally superfluous and unnecessary.

**1)**  With jQuery, you'll never need to use inline JavaScript.  Any inline JavaScript can be replaced with jQuery event listener functions.  [See jQuery `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

**2)**  However in this case, the jQuery Validate plugin already has all the various event listeners built into it.  Simply use [the built-in `submitHandler` callback function of the jQuery Validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).  It only fires if the form is valid.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/eP7kS/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#ss-form').validate({ 
        // your rules and options,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('#form_is_submitted').css('display', 'block');
            $(form).css('display', 'none');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

---

**EDIT:**

You never clearly explained what you wanted this all to do.  However, it sounds like you want [jQuery `.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and that also goes inside the `submitHandler`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#ss-form').validate({ 
        // your rules and options,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $(form).ajax({
                url:  'spreadsheet link',  // whatever url to your action
                data: $(form).serialize(),  // the form data
                success: function () {
                    $('#form_is_submitted').css('display', 'block');
                    $(form).css('display', 'none');
                }
            });
            return false;  // this is critical to prevent the page from reloading
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/cG7RW/1/**

Comment: @v2p, your OP assumes we know what you want.  We're not mind-readers.  Explain **what you want** it to do.

Comment: i create [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1OKdiKB_bWtYHldIR_agoaG2hW8_MLKcVHUXGe2A1r6o/viewform) ([form table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqmhWQ_A7q_adFZxazJLNjdaX0JOOW1CYWpTZ1pLbHc#gid=0)) and [try to use youre code](http://jsfiddle.net/v2pwww/HmVqj/)

Comment: @v2p, I forgot to send the form data with the ajax.  See my edits.

Comment: still not working, [code with edits](http://jsfiddle.net/v2pwww/HmVqj/1/). [This code working](http://jsfiddle.net/v2pwww/HmVqj/2/), but notification from google forms

Comment: @v2p, of course the second one is working... you are simply submitting the form directly with a normal page refresh.  I'm still not sure what you want from this.... if you don't want to redirect to a new page, you MUST use `ajax`.  Perhaps, Google has security in place that prevents you from doing it with `ajax`, and if that's the case, there is nothing else you can do.

Comment: thanks for your tips. I solved this problem. Need to redirect google notification in a hidden iframe and show my notification if form is valid. [See example.](http://jsfiddle.net/v2pwww/HmVqj/6/)